# How can I force the .NET ASMX WSDL generation to change a soap:address location from http to https?

Tags: wsdl, asmx

Using VB.NET asmx project, which is hosted behind SSL offload, I need to change the generated WSDL to show https for the soap:address.

```
from: <soap:address location="http://example.com/example.asmx"/>
to: <soap:address location="https://example.com/example.asmx"/>
```

preferably outside of code so we can influence in the build process.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends what system are you using** for generating the `wsdl`.
You shared that you are using VB.NET but it does not narrow down enough to answer your question a 100%. If you can show some code then we could help hopefully. Also as far as I remember, the location in the WSDL file is the same as the client is accessing it (the `URL` where it reaches). Meaning that as the offloading happens elsewhere the `location` could always be `http`.

Without further information I see three options for you:

1. Configure the TLS offloader to redirect the queries from `http` to `httpS`. (This is also a recommended setting from a security point of view.)
2. Where the offloading is happening use a solution to replace the content of the response. (This has the advantage of being specific to the environment.)
3. Use self singed certificate on the internal application as well, and therefore the address will be generated correctly. (This could be a bit tougher nut to crack, but has the benefit of not being dependent on other configuration and having to modify that configuration for every environment from development to live.)

In **c#** it could be done in code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kaevans/modify-a-web-services-wsdl-using-a-soapextensionreflector and is qite complicated. If you have a developer machine, then you need to use TLS as well... but here you go:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services.Description;

namespace Msdn.Web.Services.Samples
{
    public class HttpsReflector : SoapExtensionReflector
    {
        public override void ReflectMethod()
        {
            //no-op
        }

        public override void ReflectDescription()
        {
            ServiceDescription description = ReflectionContext.ServiceDescription;
            foreach (Service service in description.Services)
            {
                foreach (Port port in service.Ports)
                {
                    foreach (ServiceDescriptionFormatExtension extension in port.Extensions)
                    {
                        SoapAddressBinding binding = extension as SoapAddressBinding;
                        if (null != binding)
                        {
                            binding.Location = binding.Location.Replace("https://", "https://");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```